# Problems after installing Ubuntu 12.10 and GRUB

Tags: 12.10, grub2

I installed everything correctly as mentioned [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest). But after completing the installation, nothing changed in my GRUB. (There were only past releases of Ubuntu - 10.10 and 12.04 as before).

How I can start to use 12.10?

Answer (score 0):

1.Run [`boot-repair`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) disk
2.Once booted click on the `recommended repair`option from the dialog box appears.
3.Now your grub will be reinstalled or updated.